# How to move an object when a key is held down?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I know this question can be seen as a duplicate, but I spent some hours searching and figuring out what is wrong at my code.

My problem is that my object, called player, doesn't move constantly when left or right key is being held down:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == QUIT:
        self.terminate()

    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
            self.terminate()
        if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
            self.moveRight = False
            self.moveLeft = True
        if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
            self.moveLeft = False
            self.moveRight = True

    if event.type == KEYUP:
        if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
            self.moveLeft = False
        if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
            self.moveRight = False

# Move the player around
if self.moveLeft :
    # Moves the player object to left with self.PLAYERMOVERATE pixels.
    self.player.setLeftRight(-1 * self.PLAYERMOVERATE) 


if self.moveRight :
    self.player.setLeftRight(self.PLAYERMOVERATE)
```

I also tried this alternative:

```
while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.player.setLeftRight(-1 * self.PLAYERMOVERATE)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.player.setLeftRight(self.PLAYERMOVERATE)
```

Comment: what do you have in method `setLeftRight()` ? Maybe there is problem. Use `print()` to display values in variables (ie. `self.PLAYERMOVERATE` and `self.player.rect`) and to display information which part of code is executed - this way you can find mistake. Current code seems OK.

Comment: Or maybe you change position in one variable but you use different variable to display player in new position. So use `print()` to display values in variables used to display player.

Comment: The setLeftRight method contains only one line of code.  The method is :   def setLeftRight(self, pixels): self.rect.move_ip(pixels, 0). I'm pretty sure that the problem isn't here.

Comment: Please turn your code into a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), otherwise I don't think it's possible to figure out the cause of this error.

Comment: we can't see full code and run it so only what you can do is to use `print()` to check values in variables. You may have different values than you expect, or you use wrong variables in wrong places so you get unexpected results. BTW it is called "print debugging"

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are not handling the input in the main game loop.

In your code you seem to be handling the input inside a method of the object `Player`. This is not how input should be handled. In your second code example there is a `while True:` loop which will mean the loop is never exited from and thus the method's execution is never finished. I suspect that there may be a similar issue in your first example.

Instead you should:

1. Create all objects and classes.
2. Write the main game loop.

The main game loop should handle input, then process the logic of the game and then render whatever should be rendered.

Here is a short code example.

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() # Exit from pygame window
            quit() # End python thread

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                player.moveRight = False
                player.moveLeft = True
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                player.moveLeft = False
                player.moveRight = True

        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a:
                player.moveLeft = False
            if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d:
                player.moveRight = False


    # Move player using method
    if player.moveLeft:
        # Move player
    # ...


    # Render player
```

I hope that this helped you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post them in the comment section below!